# Is this okay? Because this doesn't seem ok?

Tags: discussion, questions, users

Recently, the Matrix Equation-balance literally bumped [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/63002/can-solid-rockets-aluminum-ice-have-an-advantage-when-designing-light-space-tu). They literally made no edit to the post other than to write "Need to rehabilitate this question. It would allow me to ask new questions on this site." I personally think that simply bumping to try to get out of a question ban is absouletly wrong, and based on the comment votes others seem to agree with me. I think that we should make a rule that, even if minor, an edit must at least actually change the post. This would include:

1. Adding a space
2. Adding messages that don't improve the question

If there is anything else that you feel is in the category of obvious bumping, let me know in answers/comments.

Comment: Certainly the first quoted part should be removed, meta commentary has no place in questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. It is not okay. Editing a question to improve quality, focus or currency is absolutely to be encouraged, as long as the edit doesn't break any existing questions.

This is already described in guidance - edits must be material.
Editing with no content improvement, just to bump a post, is not allowed,

If someone wants to bump a post, the [bounty process](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) gives that visibility, and rep encouragement to answer a question.

Comment: What can be done about this to prevent it @Rory Alsop

Comment: It cannot be prevented, per se, but there can be consequences

Comment: Could we make it so that when the edit is reverted, it doens't bump a second time @Rory Alsop

Comment: No, but it has already been reverted.

Comment: I know but then we have a problem. Not reverting it causes nonsense to continue to be there. Reverting is what the user wants, as it bumps again @Rory Alsop

Comment: I know. But this is the system we have. Bad behaviours do lead to suspensions, that do get longer each time, so...

Comment: I know just feels like even in the 1 year ive been here its changed so much. I never used to see bumping issue and not nearly as much spam. There weren't so much voting issues. There has been less traffic. The list continues. Also just wondering if you know, why doesn't it automatically suggest your username when I start typing it? @Rory Alsop

Comment: *Has* it been an issue? It's rude to be sure, but it isn't as though it's forcing out new, legitimate questions from the front page. I'm sure if someone were spamming edits to the extent that it was interfering with the question list, they wouldn't be editing very much longer.